# cakephp one view for many types of results

Tags: controller, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I have some controller logic:

```
public function seafood() {
$this->set('title', 'Seafood restaurants in and near Gulf Shores, AL');

$this->paginate['Restaurant']=array(
        'limit'=>9,
        'order' => 'RAND()',

        'conditions'=>array(

                'Restaurant.active'=>1,
                'Restaurant.seafood'=>'Seafood'
                )   
    );
$data = $this->paginate('Restaurant');
$this->set('seafood', $data);




}
```

This gets repeated like 13 times, with 13 different view pages labeled "seafood, waterfront, steakhouse" etc.  The view is exactly the same, everthing is the same really, except the controller has to find by a specific type of restaurant.  Can someone please explain to me how I can just make one view file that would show up at say www.site.com/restaurants/seafood?

Truth be told, all of my results pages are some variation on this.  I tell cake to paginate (and usually contain) some model's data, then stick it into a view that is almost identical (with an icon or two difference) to all the other pages.  I am building a site that is one of those "things to do and see in x beach town", so I have restaurants, places to stay, shopping, nightclubs, golf courses, etc (it is all over the place).

My boss has given me this gargantuan website to build and I really don't know any programming logic very well.  I'd like to stick to the DRY concept here so that I can really learn this stuff.

**UPDATE**

Ok, I made sure my routes had this in the file:

```
Router::connect('/restaurants/:action', array('controller'=>'restaurants'));
```

I kept my seafood.ctp file,  then took out my seafood() function and stuck this in instead:

```
 public function restaurants($restaurantType) {

$this->set('title', $restaurantType.' restaurants in and near Gulf Shores, AL');

$this->paginate['Restaurant']=array(
        'limit'=>9,
        'order' => 'RAND()',

        'conditions'=>array(

                'Restaurant.active'=>1,
                'Restaurant.seafood'=>$restaurantType
                )   
    );
$data = $this->paginate('Restaurant');
$this->set($restaurantType, $data);
}
```

When I accessed the page at www.site.com/restaurants/seafood cake told me that my controller was missing the method seafood().  What did I miss?

Comment: I think you've messed things up with trying to change the routing.  `Router::connect('/restaurants/:action', array('controller'=>'restaurants'));` You've told it to take whatever comes after restaurants as an action when in reality `restaurants` is the action and what comes after it is the parameter so naturally now it is telling you it can't find the function name `seafood()`

Comment: I removed the router::connect rule and it still is giving me the seafood() missing in controller error.

Comment: What is the name of the controller that the error is pointing to and what is the name of your actual controller?  I think you just have issues with how you are defining your URLs.  It should be something like www.mysite.com/controllername/actionname/parameter.  This is what cake looks for when it parses that URL.

Comment: It's saying the problem is in RestaurantsController.

Comment: And my actual controller is restaurants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Router::connect('/restaurants/:restaurantType', array('controller'=>'restaurants', 'action' => 'restaurants'));
```

The reason it's not finding it, is because you're still using the standard :action parameter. You just need to change it so the action remains the same, that way it gets passed into the action as parameter.

Comment: Ok, after much fiddling around in my controller, using this was the ticket.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just give the controller action a generic name like

```
public function restaurant($restaurantType) {

// Pass the parameter in via the URL for the restaurant type and use that parameter 
// as your find condition as well as the value for the title of the page

}
```

And then your URL for your link to bring up the page would look like
http://www.whatever.com/restaurant/seafood